# Check cell value in a table Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to check if a cell value in "CALENDAR" is contained in the table ams, which is located in another sheet in the same workbook but I get an error the item with the specified name not found.

```
Sub look()
 
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CALENDAR").Select
 Range("C7").Select
 
If Intersect(ActiveCell, [ams]) Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "activecell not in Table1"
Else
   MsgBox "YUP"
End If
```

Comment: What's `[ams]`?

Comment: ams is the name I gave the table - Define Name function and selected the range which this table includes

Comment: So it is a named range and not a table object?  Then use `Range("ams")` instead.

Comment: Try `If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("ams")) Is Nothing Then ...`

Comment: Tried it as Range("ams") and gor err message of method intercept of object '_global" field

Comment: not sure how you expect 2 `Range` objects from different sheets to `Intersect` ? Why not use the `Find` function ?